What's this part name and how to remove it?
I am having a coffee machine, a Grimac Tube with a pod system. And I am trying to remove/exchange the brass part, which I don't know the name of.
As you can see in the pictures, I tried it with regular tools and some force but couldn't get anywhere and probably damaged it..
The part, that I think I can replace the brass part with (please correct me if I'm wrong), I found here.



